# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) while playing audio with direct src link to backend server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, cross-origin-read-blocking

My backend is a NodeJS server, I am using [mediaserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mediaserver) package to stream audio to angular frontend. Now, I have `<audio [src]="streamLink">` where `streamLink` is the link to the backend media server which is `http://localhost:3030/music/stream?audioid=1`

Now, doing this gives me CORB error. How do I fix this.
I am using SEAN stack.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Angular can't connect to localhost backends directly, I usually solve this problem with using a Proxy server, this is also advised by Angular itself, as you can read [here](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server).